# Constant dialog-like functionality on a particular portion of a screen in a Java Swing application - is JDialog functionality the way to go?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jdialog

To expand upon the headline :

I have a screen (my main window, an encapsulated `JFrame`) that's going to be created most likely with a `GridBagLayout`, because I need a grid whose cells are to be differently-sized rectangles.  In one of these rectangles will be a malleable dialog-like functionality, with different options depending on the context of the application.

My question is, are custom JDialogs the way to go here?  Or do I simply want a reusable JPanel that has the particular buttons I want displayed or disabled depending on the context?  I hope this is clear; thanks. -B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with the `JPanel` solution.

JDialog is a heavy-weight, [top-level container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html), meaning it's window is managed by the system and cannot be embedded as a child of another component.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was thinking, wanted a expert confirmation :-).  Thanks, appreciate it.